# Ethereum Proof-of-Authority on Azure

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum

I am planning to use the new [Ethereum Proof-of-Authority on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/templates/ethereum-poa-deployment). I understand that this is suitable for an enterprise blockchain network independent from the outside public Etherum blockchain network.

Can I use the Ether cryptocurrency in this network?
If it is possible would it be a customized version of the Ether only usable in my network and not affected by the value of the currency?

Can I programmatically create Etherum wallets for users that sign up in my system and load Ether coins into their wallets?

Comment: Could you please explain why you suggest closing the question?

Comment: This is not a question about programming, so it's not a suitable question for SO. Please refer to [ask]. Next to that you're posting multiple questions in one, which is frowned upon.

Comment: Hi @rickvdbosch this is actually a question about programming as well. I assume this question would fall into the same category? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857515/what-is-blockchain-and-ethereum-where-is-it-used

Comment: Thats a pretty well conceptual question to ask...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use the Ether cryptocurrency in this network?

The answer is *technically*, yes, since this is an Ethereum blockchain network. However, the bootstrapping process of the Azure Ethereum Proof-of-Authority template does not prealocate any Ether to any pre-allocated accounts in the [Chain Specification](https://wiki.parity.io/Chain-specification) (genesis) file. Therefore, there is no Ether to begin with.

The primary reasoning behind this is that Ether serves no purpose in a private Ethereum network unless Proof-of-Work consensus is being used. Proof-of-Work in Ethereum natively requires gas to send transactions and thus the Ether equivalent of gas is necessary to transact on the network. With Proof-of-Authority consensus enabled, there are no gas costs, and thus Ether is not required.

> If it is possible would it be a customized version of the Ether only usable in my network and not affected by the value of the currency?

The Ether used on this network would belong solely to this network and has no use on any other Ethereum-based blockchain network.

> Can I programmatically create Etherum wallets for users that sign up in my system and load Ether coins into their wallets?

Again, *technically*, yes. However, this is where I disagree with the above answer. Accounts should not be created directly as part of the network aside from the initial bootstrapped Validator nodes. Accounts should be created programmatically (using a library akin to [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet)) or managed by an external wallet such as MetaMask. In fact, the Azure Ethereum PoA documentation outlines that it is [insecure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/templates/ethereum-poa-deployment#i-notice-there-are-many-transactions-on-the-network-that-i-didnt-send-where-are-these-coming-from) to unlock the personal API for account creation and that accounts should be pre-signing transactions outside of the network.

Although, again, there is no initial supply of Ether on the network and this would require you re-writing the Chain Specification and re-bootstrapping the network which is not the intention behind the Azure PoA template.

Comment: I'm just sharing an example since web3 offer features to create accounts. Of course you can always create the accounts without web3 and use other tools like MetaMask, Mist, MyEtherWallet & etc. Or, `geth account new` to keep it local without any web3 bindings.

Comment: Hi @BenBeck thanks for your answer. Do you know if we can use both Azure Ethereum  Proof-of-Authoriy and Proof-of-Work together in the same network?

Comment: @doorman, no, the networks would not be able to function together appropriately with ill-assorted consensus algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use the Ether cryptocurrency in this network?

Yes, you still have Ether (ETH) as native currency in PoA consensus Ethereum private blockchain. But, do note that if you own 10 ETH in mainnet, it doesn't mean you have 10 ETH in the private blockchain.

As for example, look at this address in [mainnet](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8557f73c1c1bead825dafe02c50aeb5ffa50f619) and [Kovan testnet](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x8557f73c1C1BeAd825dAFe02c50aEb5ffA50F619). Noticed that both addresses is `0x8557f73c1C1BeAd825dAFe02c50aEb5ffA50F619`.

*Why this happen and possible?*

Well, when you generate a private key (or if you're using hardware wallet), a public key (address) can be derived from it.

The same key can be used to manage your ETH and token balances in not just mainnet, but in all Ethereum-based networks.

> If it is possible would it be a customized version of the Ether only
>   usable in my network and not affected by the value of the currency?

Yes, the ETH in your PoA private blockchain can only be used within that network. And, it won't affect the [ETH currency value in the mainnet](https://etherscan.io/).

> Can I programmatically create Etherum wallets for users that sign up
>   in my system and load Ether coins into their wallets?

Yes, you can. Checkout web3 [`web3.eth.accounts.create()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create) and [`web3.eth.personal.newAccount()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#personal-newaccount) for that.

To load ETH into new accounts, you can use [`web3.eth.sendTransaction()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction). The sender (`from`) must be from an account that you own the private key. And of course, the sender must have enough ETH to send to the receipient (`to`).

One thing to note, you need to use the base unit called Wei in order to send ETH. 1 ETH = 1000000000000000000 Wei (18 zeros). Checkout [this tool](https://legacy.mycrypto.com/helpers.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @ZulhilmiZainudin thanks for your detailed answer. Do you know if we start with a private blockchain that expands with a growing user base, can we later on connect it to the mainnet?

Comment: @doorman, technically this would not be feasible (out-of-the-box) utilizing the bootstrapped Azure Ethereum PoA template as you would require at least a matching genesis file and network id amongst other reasons.

Comment: @doorman your probably need something like https://poa.network/bridge. Also, do checkout this article by Andras — https://medium.com/akomba/plasma-bridge-48122c554e38